# Access to the Windows Startup directory via Run 

Tags: windows, command-line

What is the command to type in the Windows Run that opens the user's Startup directory?

- it's of a format similar to **%windir%** for Windows and **%appdata%** for application data
- the site *[Computer Productivity](http://productivity.ben61a.com/windows/run.php)* has lots of the shortcuts, but not Startup

*I'm trying to reduce [RSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetitive_strain_injury), so I try to use keyboard shortcuts for as much as possible.*

Comment: "binged" is why Micros~1 search engines keep failing.

Comment: Just completed my answer, with a suggestion as to where you could have seen a shorter version of that directory.

Comment: "Keyboard shortcut" is used for key combinations like Ctrl-C rather than typed commands (even if those commands save time).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's the "shell" command. For example, I can type

```
shell:startup
```

in the *Run dialog* to pop open the `\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` directory.

There are a LOT of the "shell" commands, and a long listing is at *[Access special folders easily using the shell command](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-shell-keyword.html)*.

Comment: If you need the startup for all users, use shell:Common Startup

Answer (score 3):

Create a small VBS program `startup.vbs`:

```
set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("""" & objShell.SpecialFolders("Startup") & """")
```

This would open current user's startup folder in Windows Explorer. This would work in every still supported Windows version, in every language.

You can use `"AllUsersStartup"` instead of `"Startup"` if you need. You can read about SpecialFolders property [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ea7b5xe%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Nice tip - I'm trying to use PowerShell for all my scripting, and it's easy to forget the good things that are in VBScript

Answer (score 2):

```
"%USERPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

does work on Windows XP.

As far as I can tell, there are no further shortcuts. You can see here a list of [all variables](http://astase.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=1786) and there is no other way to reference Startup.

However, you may have seen a shorter version in some **scripting language macros**, like [Autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/macros.htm):

```
@StartupDir     current user's Startup folder
```

Comment: yeah I got that, but I've got this annoying recollection of a tip which was a lot shorter

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 7 or Windows Vista, start run:

```
c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\startup
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
```

If it doesn't work, try:

```
%UserProfile%\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
```

Or you can go define your own variable - `%st%` for example. In Windows XP it was under System Properties - Environment.

Also, the Command Prompt, combined with tab completion and `doskey` aliases is pure awesomeness, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The variable is `%username%`. So, for my account (roaming) in Windows Vista:

- Start, run,
- C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Answer (score 0):

```
cd "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```